# Symfony2: ManyToMany relation and Collection form type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm facing big issue with Collection form type for ManyToMany relation in my Symfony2 project.

Environment:
- Symfony 2.0.14
- Doctrine 2.1

Here's some code:

Post entity

```
class Post
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $title;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="posts", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="posts_tags")
 */
private $tags;

public function setTags(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $tags)
{
    foreach($tags as $tag)
    {
        $tag->addSnippet($this);
    }
}

public function addTag(\My\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
{
    $this->tags[] = $tags;
}

public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags;
}
```

Tag entity

```
class Tag
{
/**
 * @var integer $id
 * 
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string $name
 * 
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100, unique=true, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var Snippet
 * 
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="tags") 
 */
private $posts;

public function addSnippet(\My\BlogBundle\Entity\Post $posts)
{
    $this->posts[] = $posts;
}
```

PostType form class

```
->add('tags', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new TagType(),
            'allow_add' => true,
            'prototype' => true,
            'by_reference' => false,
        ))
```

Everything works perfectly, but it throws an error while inserting a tag that already exists in database `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'tag1' for key 'UNIQ_6FBC94265E237E06'`.

Do you have any workaround for this issue or am I missing something? My controller is a standard CRUD controller generated by `app/console`.`enter code here`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I don't deal much with doctrine, but seems that you are inserting a tag with the same ID/Name in the same collection. I think you could check the tag existence before insert

```
public function existTags(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $tags)
{
    foreach($this->tags as $tag)
    {
        if ( $tag->getID() === $tags->getId() )
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then

```
public function addTag(\My\BlogBundle\Entity\Tag $tags)
{
    if ( !$this->existTag($tags) );
        $this->tags[] = $tags;
}
```

These are my models:

```
namespace models;


/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="tag")
 */
class Tag
{

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    public function getId(){ return $this->id; }
    public function getName(){ return $this->name; }

    public function setId($id){ $this->id = $id; }
    public function setName($name){ $this->name = $name; }


}
```

The blog entry:

```
namespace models;

use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="entry")
 */
class Entry
{

    /**
     * @Id @Column(type="integer", nullable=false, name="id")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="string", nullable=false, name="body")
     */
    protected $body;



    /**
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag")
     * @JoinTable(name="entry_tagged",
     *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="entry_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $tags;





    public function __construct(){
        $this->tags = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function existTag(models\Tag $tag)
    {
        foreach($this->tags as $temp)
        {
            if ( $tag->getID() === $temp->getId() )
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function addTag(models\Tag $tag)
    {
        if ( !$this->existTag($tag) );
            $this->tags->add($tag);
    }


    public function getId(){ return $this->id; }
    public function getBody(){ return $this->body; }
    public function getTags(){ return $this->tags; }

    public function setId($id){ $this->id = $id; }
    public function setBody($body){ $this->body = $body; }
    public function setTags($tags){ $this->tags = $tags; }

}
```

Finally, the join table used is "entry_tagged" and looks like this:

```
entry_id | tag_id
```

Comment: It seems like it is trying to insert another tag with the same name - that's why it's a bit weird to me.

Comment: yes, for that reason you need check if the new to tah to insert already exists in $tags collection, like the method above

Comment: I've put it in the Post entity - still the same error. Am I missing something?

Comment: can you edit the post to see all Tag and Post entity attributes?

Comment: Well, I have reproduced your model and it has worked but int the posts_tags table I have included another column auto_increment as primary key. And it works fine

Comment: Thanks for your input, I deleted my entities and will create them from scratch once again. Your method has to work as I created similar entities (but with OneToMany association) and I have to check for existing extries. I just thought Doctrine is smart enough to check it on the ORM side :)

Comment: Could you share some code please. I'm definately missing something or I'm just too stupid to understand how it should work, but still geting the same error...

Comment: @DaveW, the post has been updated. Look the structure used, it avoids to have the same tag twice.